# what's a child frame in the context of a web page?

Tags: frame

What's a child frame in the context of a web page ? Is it the web page opened through a hyperlink on  a page, or is it some part of the web page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what kind of frame you're talking about.

If you're talking about the frames that were used as page layout tools, then any of the frames inside of a frameset would be consider child frames.

```
<frameset>
    <frame src="frame1content.html" /><!-- First child frame -->
    <frame src="frame2content.html" /><!-- Second child frame -->
    <frame src="frame3content.html" /><!-- Third child frame -->
</frameset>
```

If you're talking about iframes, then the child frame is the iframe. Typically this method is used to open a page from another site and embed it on your own.

```
<body>
    <div>My page content!</div>
    <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" /><!-- Child frame -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Child frame would be any [frame within a Frameset element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp). Or it may also refer to Inline Frames ([Iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp))

Comment: thanks.  Can u point me to a page which uses IFrames so that I can visualize what it is and the difference between it and opening a new page. Is it used to display ads, etc.